# How to get previous value of object (on value) in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Example Code Like below:

```
Firebase Database
   name: Sonich

when changed value
   name: Sonita


FirebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var previous_name= ?;//Sonich
  var new_name = snapshot.val(); //Sonita
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to retrieve the previous value of a node when it changes.

**Firebase doesn't provide you a solution for this, you should store the previous value somewhere.**

My solution would be to store the previous value on a node's child. You can do it this way:

1) When you want to **update** the value:

```
var new_name = "Sonich"
FireBaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var prev_name= snapshot.val(); // Sonta
  FireBaseRef.set({
    "value": new_name,
    "prev_value": prev_name
  })
});
```

2) So that you can **retrieve** the value, this way:

```
FireBaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot = snapshot.val()
  var previous_name= snapshot.prev_value;//Sonich
  var new_name = snapshot.value; //Sonita
});
```

Comment: Please don't use the priority anymore. While it is still a supported feature, there are better ways to accomplish things these days. It's just as easy to create a named child, which improves readability and maintainability.

Comment: Oh, thanks @Puf for the advice. I've used priority to store many different meta-data, is it going to be removed in the future?

Comment: That seems unlikely at the moment. But we'd rather see that developers steer away from finding new use-cases for it. :-)